# In cygwin usr/bin folder is missing

Tags: cygwin

I have installed Cygwin and once I started to build a C++ file in Visual Studio Code with Cygwin GCC, I noticed that it uses some `usr/bin` folder. Then I went to check what is in Cygwin `usr/bin` folder. But I noticed that there is no bin folder here. But there is a `sbin` folder here. Is it any glitch or normal?

Comment: Do you mean usr/bin without a leading slash? If so, this is a path relative to your current directory. Whether this directory should exist or not I can only tell if I know your current directory.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ mount
D:/cygwin64/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
D:/cygwin64/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
D:/cygwin64 on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
```

On cygwin the directory `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are the same,
similar for `/lib` and `/usr/lib`

Additional info on
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table

Comment: and what about ```/usr/sbin```?

Comment: `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin`  are separated, and usually not in the PATH